# ImageView scaling issues with horizontal image

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, imageview

I have some problem with scaling image in imageview. Here is a part of code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/dimension_ratio_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1">

            <com.ortiz.touchview.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/editor_second_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:background="@color/gray_toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/editor_divider"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/editor_divider"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <com.ortiz.touchview.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/editor_first_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/mainGreen"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editor_divider"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

I want the image scaling while maintaining its parameters and i can move or scale it. I use TouchImageView. The problem is if i put image with album orientation in first imageview i will have something like this:
[image: First image result]

But the second imageview set image as i want with the same parametres:
[image: Second image result]

How can i resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to how to stretch the image to full screen or image view without scaleType="fitXY" as it causes damage to the image. Use the following library.

[A simple imageview which scales the width or height aspect with the given ratio]

> https://github.com/santalu/aspect-ratio-imageview

To Find the aspect ratio of the device screen use the following Code.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics =this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float ratio = ((float)metrics.heightPixels / (float)metrics.widthPixels);
```